# Logic issue with lists and loops in unityscript

Tags: for-loop, arraylist, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have 3 lists: `ListOfBoxes`, `ListOfGoals` and `ListOfDoned`.

these first 2 lists contain transforms, the 3rd is empty.

When a box from `ListOfBoxes` x and z position are the same as a goals in `ListOfGoals` i move that box to `ListOfDoned`.

What I want to happen next is; If a box in the `ListOfDoned` is no longer at a goal in `ListOfGoals` move back into `ListOfBoxes`.

Here Is My Code:

```
for(var n = 0; n < ListOfGoals.Count; n++)
{
   for (var p = 0; p < ListOfBoxes.Count; p++)
   {
     if (Mathf.Abs(ListOfBoxes[p].position.x - ListOfGoals[n].position.x) < epsilon)
     {
         if (Mathf.Abs(ListOfBoxes[p].position.z - ListOfGoals[n].position.z) < epsilon)
         {
         Debug.Log("Box" + p + " has been placed at " + n);
         ListOfDoned.Add(ListOfBoxes[p]);
         ListOfBoxes.RemoveAt (p);
         break;
         }
     }
    } 
}

for (var q = 0; q < ListOfDoned.Count; q++)
{
    for (r = 0; r < ListOfGoals.Count; r++)
    {
     if (Mathf.Abs(ListOfDoned[q].position.x - ListOfGoals[r].position.x) < epsilon)
     {
         if (Mathf.Abs(ListOfDoned[q].position.z - ListOfGoals[r].position.z) < epsilon)
         {
             break;
         }
         else
         {
            if (r == ListOfGoals.Count)
            {
            ListOfBoxes.Add(ListOfDoned[q]);
            ListOfDoned.RemoveAt (q);
            }

         }
     }
    }
}
```

I can see that what is happening is that it's checking all of the goals in the list instead of exiting if it has found one, but I'm not sure what the logic would be go get this working correctly.

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT to try to add clarity] - Imagine I have 2 boxes in `ListOfBoxes` and 2 goals in `listofgoals`. When 1 box moves to the same position as one of the goals (only x and z axis, not y) I want that box removed from `ListOfBoxes` to `ListOfDoned`. That's the first nested for loop, and it seems to be working fine. However if that box is later moved from the same position as one of those goals I need it back in `ListOfBoxes`.  This is what I want the second nested for loop to do.

What appears to be happening is that it is comparing the boxes in `listOfDoned` with all of the goals in `listofgoals` and (even though it has the same position as one of the goals) it doesnt have the same position as the other one so the else case and put the box in the list `listofboxes`.

**I need to check against the position of all the goals, and as long as it's position is the same as one of them, don't do anything, else return it to `listOfBoxes`.**

Comment: this is why i stay far away from nested `for` loops

Comment: Just wondering, is your last comment referring to the first or second set of nested loops? Any additional details you can provide on the unexpected behaviour you're experiencing?

Comment: It was referring to the second set of nested loops. What appears to be happening is it takes the first box from `ListOfDoned` and checks it's position against the position of the goals in `ListOfGoals`. So far so good. But what is happening is it always moves the box back to list `ListOfBoxes` because there is more than 1 goal, so even if it is in the correct position for one goal in `ListOfGoals`, the else case will be run anyway because it isn't in the position of the others.

Comment: @user3166360 Hmmm...so the `break` actually gets called inside the second set of nested loops, but it continues iterating through the remaining items anyways? Can you verify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [PipsqueakGames](https://twitter.com/PipsqueakGames/status/637444422234312704) on twitter for helping me reach this solution.

```
for(var n = 0; n < ListOfGoals.Count; n++)
{
   for (var p = 0; p < ListOfBoxes.Count; p++)
   {
     if (Mathf.Abs(ListOfBoxes[p].position.x - ListOfGoals[n].position.x) < epsilon)
     {
         if (Mathf.Abs(ListOfBoxes[p].position.z - ListOfGoals[n].position.z) < epsilon)
         {
         Debug.Log("Box" + p + " has been placed at " + n);
         ListOfDoned.Add(ListOfBoxes[p]);
         ListOfBoxes.RemoveAt (p);
         break;
         }
     }
    } 
}

for (q = 0; q < ListOfDoned.Count; q++)
{
    var matched:boolean = false;
    for (r = 0; r < ListOfGoals.Count; r++)
    {
        if (Mathf.Abs(ListOfDoned[q].position.x - ListOfGoals[r].position.x) < epsilon)
        {
            if (Mathf.Abs(ListOfDoned[q].position.z - ListOfGoals[r].position.z) < epsilon)
            {
                matched = true;
                Debug.Log("Box" + q + " is still at " + r);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!matched)
    {
        ListOfBoxes.Add(ListOfDoned[q]);
        ListOfDoned.RemoveAt (q);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not being able to solve what was wrong on my end - but I'm glad you were able to find a solution that worked for you. You definitely should consider iterating backwards like PipsqueakGames suggested though - that's something that could lead to unexpected behaviour if not addressed.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT: This answer addresses what I believe is a problem in your code, but I don't think it fixes the behaviour you describe in your comments. Let me revise this pending more clarification.]

I believe the problem you describe is due to your `if` statement inside the second nested loop:

```
if (r == ListOfGoals.Count)
{
    ListOfBoxes.Add(ListOfDoned[q]);
    ListOfDoned.RemoveAt (q);
}
```

You need to remember that the contents of your loop will only execute if the condition you specified in your `for` loop is true. In this case, that is

```
r < ListOfGoals.Count
```

This means that your `if` condition `r == ListOfGoals.Count` can never occur, because the loop will terminate before `r` ever reaches up to `ListOfGoals.Count`. Since the condition never evaluates to `true`, items will never be moved from `ListOfDoned` to `ListOfBoxes`, even if they're supposed to be.

To fix this, I suggest changing your `if` statement to:

```
if (r == ListOfGoals.Count - 1)
{
    ListOfBoxes.Add(ListOfDoned[q]);
    ListOfDoned.RemoveAt (q);
}
```

Which would correspond to the last execution of the loop. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that. You're right that this doesn't address the main issue which I believe is with the `break`. I'll try to elaborate further. Imagine I have 2 boxes in `ListOfBoxes` and 2 goals in `listofgoals`. When 1 box moves on to one of the goals I want that box moved to `ListOfDoned`. That's the top nested for loop, and seems to be working fine. However if that box is later moved from one of those goals I need it back in `ListOfBoxes`.

Comment: What appears to be happening is that it is comparing the boxes in `listOfDoned` with all of the goals in `listofgoals` and because (even though it is on one of the goals) it isn't on the other one will run the else case and return it to the list `listofboxes`. I need to check against the position of all the goals, and as long as it's position is the same as one of them, don't do anything, else return it to the list.